How do you derive the antiderivative of the Tractrix integral?
I'm referring to the integral listed here
It is an integral of the form
$$\newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}}
\int \frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x} \, dx
$$
Trigonometric substitution doesn't work that well, so I used hyperbolic substitution by setting
$$ 
x = a \tanh(\theta)
$$
since
$$
\sech^2(\theta) + \tanh^2(\theta) = 1,
\qquad 
a\sech(\theta) = a\sqrt{1 - \tanh^2(\theta)}, 
$$
where
$$\theta = \tanh^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{x}{a}\Bigr) 
\quad\implies\quad
d\theta = \frac{a}{a^2 - x^2}\,dx.
$$
This makes our integrand
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x} \, dx 
&= \frac{\sech(\theta)}{\tanh(\theta)} \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{d\theta}{\cosh(\theta)} \cdot 
\frac{\cosh(\theta)}{\sinh(\theta)} \\
&= \frac{d\theta}{\sinh(\theta)} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}{x} \cdot \frac{a \, dx}{a^2 - x^2} \\
&= \frac{a \, dx}{x\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}
\end{aligned}
$$
The integrand is now in the form of a derivative of an inverse hyperbolic function so we have
$$ 
a\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}
= -a \sech^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{x}{a}\Bigr) 
= -a\ln\biggl( \frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}{x} \biggr) + C
$$
However, when we differentiate the above function we get
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \Biggl( -a\ln\biggl(\frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}{x}\biggr) \Biggr) 
= \frac{a^2}{x\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}, 
$$
which is not our original integrand. But if we add
$$
\frac{-x^2}{x\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}
$$
to the above equation is simplifies to the original integrand.
And
$$
\frac{-x^2}{x\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}} 
= \frac{-x}{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}} 
= \frac{d}{dx}\Bigl( \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} \Bigr)
$$
so our correct antiderivative is
$$ 
F(x) = \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} - a\ln\biggl( \frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}{x} \biggr).
$$
I did find an old calculus book which listed this integral in the table of integrals but how can it be derived directly from the original integrand so that you get the complete antiderivative rather than just one part of it?

You didn't ask about this, but the (circular) trig substitution $x = a\sin\theta$ works just fine, yielding
$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x},\mathrm{d}x = a\int\bigl(\csc\theta - \sin\theta\bigr),\mathrm{d}\theta,
$$
which has standard antiderivative and easy back-substitution into the variable $x$, yielding the same answer.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2940407/1157207

Let $x=a\sin \theta$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x} d x & =\int \frac{a \cos \theta}{a \sin \theta} \cdot a \cos \theta d \theta \\
& =a \int \frac{\cos ^2 \theta}{\sin \theta} d \theta \\
& =a \int \frac{1-\sin ^2 \theta}{\sin \theta} d \theta \\
& =a \int(\csc \theta-\sin \theta) d \theta \\
& =a(-\ln |\csc \theta+\cot \theta|+\cos \theta)+C \\
& =a\left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a}-\ln \left|\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x}\right|\right)+C \\
& =\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-a \ln \left|\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x}\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Thanks. I should have stuck with trig substitution rather than bothered with hyperbolic substitution.


$$ \newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}}
a\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}
= -a \sech^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{x}{a}\Bigr) 
= -a\ln\biggl( \frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}{x} \biggr) + C
$$

Let's be a tad more careful. We have
$$\newcommand{\arsech}{\operatorname{arsech}}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\begin{align*}
a \int \frac{\dd x}{x \sqrt{a^2-x^2}}
&= 
a \int \frac{\dd x}{ax \sqrt{1-(x/a)^2}}\\
&= 
  \int \frac{\dd x}{ x \sqrt{1-(x/a)^2}}\\
&= 
 \frac 1 a \int \frac{\dd x}{ (x/a) \sqrt{1-(x/a)^2}}
\end{align*}$$
Let $u = \frac x a$:
$$
 \int \frac{du}{ u\sqrt{1-u^2}}
= -\arsech u + C
= -\arsech \frac x a +C
$$
This corrected errant factor of $a$ will then give your earlier-cited derivative,

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \Biggl( -a\ln\biggl(\frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}{x}\Biggr) \Biggr) 
= \frac{a^2}{x\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}, 
$$

the correct form
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \Biggl( - \ln\biggl(\frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}{x}\Biggr) \Biggr) 
= \frac{a }{x\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}, 
$$
and your earlier work establishes this as the integrand:

$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x} \, dx 
&= \frac{\sech(\theta)}{\tanh(\theta)} \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{d\theta}{\cosh(\theta)} \cdot 
\frac{\cosh(\theta)}{\sinh(\theta)} \\
&= \frac{d\theta}{\sinh(\theta)} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}{x} \cdot \frac{a \, dx}{a^2 - x^2} \\
&= \frac{a \, dx}{x\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}
\end{aligned}
$$

